# Does the silver block at the end of demo have any use?

Tags: the-talos-principle

At the end of [Talos Principle demo playthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWPyBgqBf0s) (22:11), there is a silver block rewarded to the player. Does this one have any use, either in the demo or in the later part of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things are also sigils(tetrominos). There are total of 9 silver/gray sigils in game, A-B-C levels have 3 each on their star-doored levels (I really don't know what to call those levels).

**Edit:** And yes, they are used in some place in game.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the silver sigils in the main game have a use, but the original question was about the demo, not the main game.

And, as far as I can tell, the silver sigil from the recorder puzzle in the demo has no use whatsoever. You can easily find and use the paint can without solving that puzzle. All you have to do to get it is get to the hub area after solving the fan-based puzzle.